# Dialogflow phone gateway integration issue

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, ivr, dialogflow-cx

I am using Dialogflow es version and want to use Dialogflow phone gateway integration
so a little bit of background, I am now able to integrate it and I got us a phone number and all the basic things are working but if I use custom webhook it is not working currently  I am categorizing like this in the webhook node.js function

```
if (agent.requestSource == 'GOOGLE_TELEPHONY') {
        agent.add('test test');
}else{
        agent.add('not telephony');
}
```

but it is not working any suggestions?

note If I add something in the dialogflow console itself it is working but not with the custom webhook code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to work with Google Telephony but I recommend you to try Voximplant Telephony integration for both ES and CX.

I leave a tutorial here, you can create an account for free -> https://youtu.be/6QCN0IXVpQ8

Let me know if you need any help with it.